# What does 'P' stand for in the DateInterval format?

Tags: php, php-5.3

Consider the following example quoted from [php manual for DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php)

```
<?php
  $date = new DateTime('2000-01-20');
  $date->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

'D' is for days, what does the 'P' stand for in that formatting?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)

> Interval specification.
>
> The format starts with the letter P, for "period." Each duration period is represented by an integer value followed by a period designator. If the duration contains time elements, that portion of the specification is preceded by the letter T.

Answer (score 26):

'P' stands for Period.
see here http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

Comment: That's crazy, so many examples use `P` but that reference is so understated. I guessed it meant period and I was searching `php.net` for that word, I obviously never got to the constructor page.. But it's not referenced on `date_format`, `DateTime::diff`, `DateTime::format`, `DateInterval`, and a host of general `Date/Time` functions. I wanted to know if there were any other prefixes to know about and be damned if I could find it til I came to stack exchange

Answer (score 19):

I think it can be answered in more details. First of all, `DateInterval` constructor method takes one parameter named `$interval_spec` which is string.

```
DateInterval::__construct ( string $interval_spec )
```

This parameter has a specification described as below:

> The format starts with the letter P, for period. Each duration period
>   is represented by an integer value followed by a period designator. If
>   the duration contains time elements, that portion of the specification
>   is preceded by the letter T.

There are some Period Designators that are used in the argument:

- **Y** for **years**
- **M** for **months**
- **D** for **days**
- **W** for **weeks**. These get converted into days, so can not be combined with D.
- **H** for **hours**
- **M** for **minutes**
- **S** for **seconds**

Let's see some example using Period Designators:

- Two days is P2D.
- Two seconds is PT2S.
- Six years and five minutes is P6YT5M.

There is an order that needs to be maintained as described the doc:

> The unit types must be entered from the largest scale unit on the left
>   to the smallest scale unit on the right. So years before months,
>   months before days, days before minutes, etc. Thus one year and four
>   days must be represented as P1Y4D, not P4D1Y.

**The specification can also be represented as a datetime**.

- One year, two months, four days would be P0001-02-04T00:00:00

But the values in this format can not exceed a given period's roll-over-point (e.g. 25 hours is invalid).